# WMS with QGIS-Server: missing legend

Tags: wms, qgis-server

I have set up QGIS-server for a WMS. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and QGIS 2.10. When loading the WMS in QGIS or Mapbender3 the symbology in the layertree is missing for points and lines. It works with polygons. Under Ubuntu 15.04 I did not face this problem.

Any ideas?

[image: QGIS legend error report]

Comment: Does the GetLegendGraphic request work in a browser for your layer?   hint: you can find it in your GetCapabilities response.

Comment: No, it doesn't (Internal Server Error)! The GetLegendGraphic request for the polygon layers works.